# Error Java Spring "URL must start with jdbc"

Tags: java, spring

**Settings.xml**

```
<!--put this file in C:\Users\User\.m2-->
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>development</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>env</name>
                    <value>dev</value>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <db.url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/creativecreators</db.url>
                <db.driverClassName>com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</db.driverClassName>
                <db.username>root</db.username>
                <db.password></db.password>
                <sql.dialect>org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</sql.dialect>
            </properties>
        </profile>

    </profiles>

</settings>
```

**Application.properties**

```
#logging file properties
logging.file.path=./logs
logging.file.name=${logging.file.path}/game.log
#application properties
spring.application.name=creativecreators-service
#liquibase properties
spring.liquibase.enabled=true
spring.liquibase.drop-first=false
spring.liquibase.change-log=classpath:db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml
spring.liquibase.url=@db.url@
spring.liquibase.user=@db.username@
spring.liquibase.password=@db.password@
#database properties
spring.datasource.url=@db.url@
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.username=@db.username@
spring.datasource.password=@db.password@
spring.datasource.testWhileIdle=true
spring.datasource.validationQuery=SELECT 1
#jpa properties
# Show or not log for each sql query
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, update)
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults=false
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=@sql.dialect@

security.jwt.url=/authenticate/login
security.jwt.header=Authorization
security.jwt.header.prefix=Bearer
security.jwt.expiration=1800000
security.jwt.secret=asdkaowdkaowkdar12r3141r13d13eWWDW21e12dDWD2112313t1fed
```

**Error**

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/liquibase/LiquibaseAutoConfiguration$LiquibaseConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase]: Factory method 'liquibase' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URL must start with 'jdbc'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:656) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:636) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1108) ~[spring-context-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:868) ~[spring-context-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at Backend.Server.ServerApplication.main(ServerApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase]: Factory method 'liquibase' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URL must start with 'jdbc'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:651) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URL must start with 'jdbc'
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.isTrue(Assert.java:118) ~[spring-core-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.jdbc.DatabaseDriver.fromJdbcUrl(DatabaseDriver.java:271) ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder.maybeGetDriverClassName(DataSourceBuilder.java:82) ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder.build(DataSourceBuilder.java:74) ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.liquibase.LiquibaseAutoConfiguration$LiquibaseConfiguration.createNewDataSource(LiquibaseAutoConfiguration.java:145) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.liquibase.LiquibaseAutoConfiguration$LiquibaseConfiguration.createSpringLiquibase(LiquibaseAutoConfiguration.java:127) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.liquibase.LiquibaseAutoConfiguration$LiquibaseConfiguration.liquibase(LiquibaseAutoConfiguration.java:100) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    ... 22 common frames omitted
```

I use settings.xml in Application properties. As you see, in <db.url> I started with "jdbc" and there is no any other place that I have an another link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code looks fine. is 'development' profile enabled?